# Minimum number of circles to fill up a square

Tags: combinatorics

Suppose there is a square each of side $a$. I want to fill the square with circle of radius $r$. How many overlapping circles are needed to fill up the square?

Comment: exactly filling it up is not possible i guess, it becomes a quite tedious calculation ain't it?

Comment: anyway related to this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7946152/ideas-for-an-algorithm-for-random-distribution-of-circles-in-a-square ?

Comment: There probably is no "nice" exact formula for arbitrary a and r, but an overlapping hexagonal cover will be asymptotically optimal.

Comment: Thank you very much for  answers.